# How to connect mySql database using sequel pro?

Tags: mysql, database

I created database.
I want to access that database with using sequelPro.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok now this will soley depend on where this database is located if it is an online database being hosted on a webserver with a domain follow these instructions :

1. open sequel pro
2. choose SSH by the connection details
3. Start entering the server information of where the database is
   stored just like in the image below

[image: screenshot example i got from the internet]

*Please enter your site number wherever you see  # in the image i have attached , also where you have the username in this example im assuming your mysql database user is db(sitenumber) just so that you do not forget your site number however it can be whatever you want it to be.Your password sections on this screen all refer to the user password that you have given to the user in your SQL domain part .

Also where you see .gridservice.com you will need to replace that with your access domain remember all these instructions only apply if you are using grid sharing server .When all your details are correctly placed in the textboxes provided then click connect.That should do it ! hope i was helpfull :-)

Now just incase you plan on connecting to a mysql database on localhost say for instance one created on wamp server just follow these easy steps and you should be fine :

1. open sequel pro
2. choose standard connection by the connection details
3. enter you connection details as seen below

[image: connecting locally]

*The local connection should be much easier then the online connection.We must ensure that you MYsql is running before we attempt the connection in the case that you are using wamp server then we would click on start all services button.Next we must input the connection details , the host can be kept as 127.0.0.1 since we are connecting locally however the user and password would need to be created before attempting a connection these are done from within you local server .The login details must be entered correctly in the user and password sections and are case sensitive.Then we input the name of our database and the port number can be kept as 3306.Please don't hesitate in asking any questions im here to help :-)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a connection specify the database or connect and after this select the database from the list.

You may also use sql to choose the database with `use myDatabase`